# Proving that sequence is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Given $|x_n| \leq y_n$ for all $n \in N$, and $(y_n)$ is a convergent sequence, prove that $(x_n)$ is bounded as well.

My attempt:
Let, $\lim(y_n) = a,$ then since $|x_n| \leq y_n$ for all $n,$ we have $|x_n| \leq a.$ Hence, ($|x_n|$) is bounded by $a.$

How do I now go about proving $(x_n)$ is bounded as well?

Comment: $y_n \to a$ does not mean $y_n \leq a$ for all $n$.

Comment: How do you show a converging sequence is bounded? This is an exercise that tests your understanding of a proof, rather than asking you to directly apply a proposition you've learned.

Comment: The set $U=\{x:\ |x|<|a|+1\}$ is open and contains $a$. Therefore, all the terms of $y_n$, except for finitely many, are inside $U$. Call $y_{n_1},y_{n_2},...,y_{n_k}$ be the finitely many points that fall outside $S$. Then $S=\{x:\ |x|\leq \max(|a|+1,|y_{n_1}|,...,|y_{n_k}|)\}$ is a closed ball that contains all $y_n$. Since $|x_n|<y_n\leq |y_n|$ it also contains all $x_n$. Therefore, $x_n$ is bounded.

Comment: A picture could be worth a thousand words here, if you start drawing out a random nonnegative sequence $y_n$ converging to something and another sequence $x_n$ with $|x_n|\leq y_n$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

" $\lim(y_n) = a$, then since $∣x_n∣ ≤ y_n$ for all $n$, we have $∣x_n∣ ≤ a$ "

is not necessarily true.

You may alter it to

"since  $\lim(y_ n) = a$, we have $ y_n \le M$ for some $M>0$ and since $∣x_n∣ ≤ y_n$ for all $n$, we have $∣x_n∣\le M "$

We know that $- ∣x_n∣\le  x_n \le ∣x_n∣ $, so $x_n$ is bunded.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof of boundedness of $(y_n)$ is flawed, because if $a$ is the limit, it's not necessarily true that $y_n\le a$.

Note that $y_n\ge0$.

If $a$ is the limit of $(y_n)$, there exists $N$ such that, for $n>N$, $|y_n-a|<1$, so $y_n<1+a$. If $\bar{y}=\max\{y_n:0\le n\le N\}$, then $y_n\le \bar{y}+1+a$ for every $n$.

Hence $(y_n)$ is bounded. As $0\le|x_n|\le y_n\le\bar{y}+1+a$, also $(|x_n|)$ is a bounded sequence.

Now we can prove that if $(|x_n|)$ is a bounded sequence, then $(x_n)$ is bounded as well. If $|x_n|\le c$, for every $n$, then
$$
-c\le x_n\le c
$$
for every $n$.

Answer (score 0):

If we let $\lim y_n =a$ as you suggest than that means for any $\epsilon$ there is an $N$ so that $|a-y_n|<\epsilon$.  So $y_n < a + \epsilon$.

Now $\{x_1,.... , x_N\}$ is finite and so there exist $MAX = \max \{|x_i|\}$ if $n \le N$ then $-MAX \le x_n \le MAX$.  And if $n > N$ then $-|a + \epsilon| < x_n < |a +\epsilon|$

So for any $x_k$,  $-\max (MAX, |a+ \epsilon|) \le x_k \le \max(MAX, |a + \epsilon|)$.

Answer (score -1):

Try thinking about how $|x_n|\leq y_n$ is the same as $|x_n-0|\leq y_n$.

As $y_n$ is bounded we know there exist some upper bound $U$, we also know that $y_n \ge0$ as $y_n\ge|x_n|$ so $|y_n|=y_n<U$

And $|x_n|\le y_n <U$

At very least $x_n$ is bounded by $+U,-U$

Comment: This is what I just thought.
Since, ($y_n$) is convergent, let's say to some a $\in$ $R$. Then by definition of convergence of sequence, for any epsilon greater than zero, there exists a n $\in$ $N$ such for n $>$ $N$, $y_n$ $<$ a + $\epsilon$, hence, by transitivity, $\mid $$x_n$$ \mid$ $<$ a + $\epsilon$, so ($\mid $$x_n$$ \mid$) is bounded. Is this correct?

Comment: You say for any epsilon. You have to fix one. Say $\epsilon = 1$. You can then find an index $m$ such that after $m$ the tail of the sequence is bounded. And there are only finitely many terms before the bounded tail. So you can bound them easily and hence you can bound the entire sequence.